# Use ActiveMQ 5 and IBM MQ 8 in the same application

Tags: activemq-classic, ibm-mq

I have a java application that connects to both ActiveMQ and IBM MQ.  I'm currently using IBM MQ 7.1 and trying to upgrade to use the MQ 8.0 client.  The MQ 8 jars reference JMS 2.0 classes, like JMSRuntimeException.  the ActiveMQ-all jar includes JMS 1.1 classes which conflict with JMS 2.0.

Is there any way to utilize both?

Comment: In an OSGi container that could work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way you can do it is to use the direct WebsphereMQ classes and NOT use it as a JMS provider, then your conflict will evaporate.

Comment: Thanks, that might be the answer I accept although it is a large amount of work for this particular application.